# Compare two number in shell

Tags: shell, sh

how can I compare numbers in my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
service=myservice

if [ $(ps | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ]  
then
  echo "$service is running!!!"
else
  echo "$service is NOT running!!!"
fi
```

the above is not working

Comment: No need to compare numbers. Use `pgrep -f "$service" >/dev/null && echo " $service running"`

Comment: @anubhava : thanks, how can I put this command on a script shell? to be able to restart the service if not running?

Comment: thanks I put it in a shell script

Answer (score 0):

Using git bash:

```
$ if ((9 > 2 )); then
> echo 'hello'
> fi
hello
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that I am running a customized linux distribution for ARM and I need to use shell script

Comment: Woulnd't that just be`if [ "$a" -lt "$b" ];then
  echo "a is smaller than b";
fi`

Comment: thanks,  I tried this but it is not working `if [ $(ps | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) -lt 0 ]` it gives me service not running weather it is running or not

Comment: **-lt** means "less than". As `wc` will always return a number >= 0, so it is always true. You need **-gt**  ("greater than") instead

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @anubhava, I made this script

```
#!/bin/sh
service=myService

if pgrep "$service" > /dev/null
then
  echo "$service is running!!!"
else
  echo "$service is NOT running!!!"
fi
```